# uWSGI error every time I use the requests module in Django app on Docker

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, python-requests, uwsgi

I'm running a Django app with uWSGI in Docker with docker-compose. I get the same error every time I:

1. Send a POST request with AJAX
2. In handling said request in my view, I use python's requests module, i.e. `r = requests.get(some_url)`

uWSGI says the following:

```
!!! uWSGI process 13 got Segmentation Fault !!!
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 13) died :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 24)
spawned 4 offload threads for uWSGI worker 1
```

The console in the browser says `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

I've tried using the requests module in different places, and wherever I put it I get the same Segmentation Fault error. I'm also able to run everything fine outside of docker with no errors, so I've narrowed it down to: `docker + requests module = errror`.

Is there something that could be blocking the requests sent with the requests module from within the docker container? Thanks in advance for your help.

Here's my **uwsgi.ini** file:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir           = %d
module          = my_project.wsgi:application
master          = true
processes       = 2
http            = 0.0.0.0:8000
vacuum          = true
pidfile         = /tmp/my_project.pid
daemonize       = %d/my_project.log
check-static    = %d
static-expires  = /* 7776000
offload-threads = %k
uid             = 1000
gid             = 1000
# there is no /etc/mime.types on the docker Arch Linux image
mime-file       = %d/mime.types
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM alpine:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /my_project
WORKDIR /my_project

RUN apk add build-base python3-dev py3-pip python3

# deps for python cryptography
RUN apk add libffi-dev musl-dev openssl-dev

# dep for uwsgi
RUN apk add linux-headers

ADD requirements.txt /my_project/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /my_project/

ENTRYPOINT ./start.sh
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    entrypoint: ./start.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/my_project
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - DEBUG_LEVEL=INFO
    network_mode: "host"
```

**start.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo '' > logfile.log
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
tail -f logfile.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Change base image to Ubuntu 16.04 and everything works fine now.